# Local website not working internally except with hosts entry

Tags: networking

I have a local apache2 and Concrete5 driven website. `https://www.msgkmg.com`
If I have an entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.2.XXX www.msgkmg.com
```

I can hit the site fine from any pc on the lan
If I am at home (off-site) I can hit the site fine.

PROBLEM: If I delete the entry in hosts and try to get to the website 
from a computer on the lan it will never resolve.
Traceroute goes nowhere. 
It should leave the building looking for a DNS entry. 
Finding it then it should come back in through the router to the server.
it never works. HELP

```
Kubuntu 14.04 updated.
Asus RT-N66W running the latest merlin software.
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  There was some strange script buried in my Asus Router.  A factory reset solved the problem.